# How to sort the fields by specific values in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I want to select the fields from **DB** but I want the first fields which

```
Flag ='true'
```

I wrote this code:

```
SELECT     
    ID, File, Flag
FROM  Media 
ORDER BY Flag = 'true'
```

Comment: what is the type of Flag? and what do you actually want to SELECT after your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a bit(Boolean) field then use following as you want 1(true) to appear before 0(false):

```
SELECT  ID, 
    File,
    Flag
 FROM  Media 
 Order by Flag DESC
```

If it's a string(varchar) field use following. I'm assuming you have true or false as values in the column.

```
SELECT  ID, 
    File,
    Flag
 FROM  Media 
 Order by Flag
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that;select rows which have Flag="True" field in ascending order

```
SELECT     ID, File,Flag
           FROM  Media 
           WHERE Flag="true"
           Order by Flag ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a fourth column that dictate an sort order!

```
SELECT     
    ID,
    File,
    Flag,
    CASE WHEN Flag = 'true' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS SortColumn
FROM  Media 
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Or you can divide it into two selects with an `UNION` between!

```
SELECT ID, [File], Flag FROM Media WHERE Flag = 'true'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, [File], Flag FROM Media WHERE Flag <> 'true' OR Flag IS NULL
```